# sed '$' matching start of line instead of end

Tags: bash, awk, sed, carriage-return

I am trying to append '.tsv' to the end of a column of text in a file.

You can do this easily with `sed 's|$|.tsv|' myfile.txt`

However, this is not working for my file, and I am trying to figure out why and how to fix it so that this works.

The column I want to edit looks like this:

```
$ cut -f12 chickspress.tsv | sort -u | head
Adipose_proteins
Adrenal_gland
Cerebellum
Cerebrum
Heart
Hypothalamus
Ovary
Sciatic_nerve
Testis
Tissue
```

But when I try to use `sed`, the result comes out wrong:

```
$ cut -f12 chickspress.tsv | sort -u | sed -e 's|$|.tsv|'
.tsvose_proteins
.tsvnal_gland
.tsvbellum
.tsvbrum
.tsvt
.tsvthalamus
.tsvy
.tsvtic_nerve
.tsvis
.tsvue
.tsvey
.tsvr
.tsv
.tsvreas
.tsvoral_muscle
.tsventriculus
```

the `.tsv` is supposed to be at the end of the line, not the front.

I thought there might be some whitespace error, so I tried this (macOS):

```
$ cut -f12 chickspress.tsv | sort -u | cat -ve
Adipose_proteins^M$
Adrenal_gland^M$
Cerebellum^M$
Cerebrum^M$
Heart^M$
Hypothalamus^M$
Ovary^M$
Sciatic_nerve^M$
Testis^M$
Tissue^M$
kidney^M$
liver^M$
lung^M$
pancreas^M$
pectoral_muscle^M$
proventriculus^M$
```

This `^M` does not look right, its not present in my other files, but I am not sure what it is representing here or how to fix it or just get this `sed` command to work around it.

I produced this file using Python's `csv.DictWriter` in a script which I've used many times in the past but never noticed this error coming from its output before. Run on macOS in this case.

Comment: Your file has DOS line endings. You can use this `sed`: `sed $'s~\\r$~.tsv~'`

Comment: ...or use `dos2unix` if you have it installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per Ed's comment, in case you want to remove carriage returns at last of lines only then following may help.

```
awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")} 1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

OR

```
sed -i.bak '#s#\r$##' Input_file
```

---

Remove the control M characters by doing following and then try your command.

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file  && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Or if you have `dos2unix` utility in your system you could use that too for removing these characters.

With `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"")} 1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

With `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's#\r##g' Input_file
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. Did not realize that `^M` was how these characters are represented

Comment: If you don't have `dos2unix` then you should use `sed 's/\r$//'`, not `tr -d '\r'` as the former just does what you want which is to remove `\r` from line endings while the latter removes `\r`s in **every** context, including if/when they are relevant (e.g. within fields in some CSVs). In awk it'd be `sub(/\r$/,"")`, not `gsub(/\r/,"")`.

Comment: @EdMorton, sure Ed added that now in my answer, thanks for guiding as usual :)